# Female bastards in Game of Thrones

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the *Game of Thrones* universe, some men have sons with women who are not their wives. That means those sons are bastards and they get the surname Snow.

But what if the man has a daughter?

**Q: What happens to female bastards in the *Game of Thrones* universe? Would their surname also follow the same pattern? Are they just killed off?**

I am up-to-date on the TV series (season 4) but not on the books. Please try not to spoil content from beyond where the TV series is currently at.

Comment: “Bastardettes”, as it were.

Comment: Related: [List of known Bastard daughters in Westeros](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131240/is-there-any-known-bastard-daughter-in-westeros)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are just like the male bastards. If you are up to date with the TV series you must have seen on the first and second episode of the fourth season a girl that was with Prince Oberyn that had 'Sand' as a last name. 'Sand' is the last name people give bastards in Dorne. (I think the name was mentioned the second episode)

Not every bastard has 'Snow' for a last name. Here is the list with the bastards' last names:

```
Region       Surname        Example Character
Reach        Flowers        Ser Robert Flowers
Westerlands  Hill           Joy Hill
Iron Islands Pyke           Wex Pyke
Riverlands   Rivers         Walder Rivers
Dorne        Sand           Nymeria Sand
North        Snow           Jon Snow
Vale         Stone          Mya Stone
Stormlands   Storm          Ser Rolland Storm
Crownlands   Waters         Aurane Waters
```

(Source: [Wikia](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bastardy#Surnames) -- **Do not click on the link if you are afraid you'll get spoilers.**)

Τhis image might help you even more:

[image]

The female ones from the list are [Joy Hill](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Joy_Hill), [Mya Stone](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mya_Stone) and [Nymeria Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Nymeria_Sand).

The bastard that was with Prince Oberyn was [Ellaria Sand](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ellaria_Sand):

[image]

Comment: Addendum: Roger Waters has nothing to do with the Crownlands

Comment: Excellent answer. A source for the table would be good.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic if we can have [Lord Elmo and Lord Kermit](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kermit_Tully), of House Tully, we can certainly have a Rhaegar Waters

Comment: Elmo Tully was grandson of Grover Tully, and father of Kermit :)

Answer (score 13):

Let's start with a comment on the surname. The surname of a bastard is not necessarily "Snow". It is in fact depending on your place of birth. In the North, bastards are called Snow. In the Riverlands it is Rivers, in the Vale Stone, in Dorne you will be called Sand and so on. There is a list of the different surnames in the [Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bastardy), but you will want to avoid it, as the article contains spoilers and it is tempting click the links to read further spoilers.

The link can also answer your question: Female bastards are not killed off (at least not in general), as we know several living female bastards. There are a couple of female bastards that are known. I expect at least one of them to appear in Season 4. I put the ones that appear in the book in spoiler tags:

> There is a girl called Mya Stone, living in the Vale. She is the bastard daughter of Robert Baratheon and appeared in book one. Her role was not important in that book, but she appeared later again, we still have to see, what happens to her in the TV show.
>  Then there are the "Sand Snakes", a group of bastard daughters of Oberyn Martell from Dorne. The mother of one of them (Ellaria Sand) is also a female bastard, I expect that she appears in Season 4, probably with one of the Sand Snakes (But I also expect that for the TV series they merge those characters into only one or two).

But you have already seen a female bastard on screen: A bastard daughter of Robert Baratheon was killed in the first episode of Season 2. Yes, she was killed off, so strictly speaking she does not count as an example. But the reason that she was killed was that she threatened Joffrey's claim to the throne, not because she was female. Had Robert lived, she could have lived herself under the name Waters (as bastards are named in the Crownlands and King's Landing).