# Is there any known bastard daughter in Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the realm there are good number of bastard sons (most famous being Jon Snow and Ramsay) but I did not observe any bastard daughters. Is there any bastard daughter mentioned in the story till now?

Comment: Dunno about books, but in the show, all female bastards are all about hissing with their sistsers

Comment: Related: [Female bastards in Game of Thrones](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54333/female-bastards-in-game-of-thrones)

Comment: Cersei Lannister is a daughter, and she's definitely a bastard, through and through.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Many bastard daughters are mentioned in the story. The nomenclature rules are same as the ones used for naming their male counterparts i.e. Stone, Hill, Pyke, Snow, Sand, Rivers and Waters. Some of the female bastards of aristocrats are following:

### Current Timeline

Following female bastards are mentioned for on-going timeline in ASOIAF.

1. [Mya Stone](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mya_Stone) is bastard daughter of Robert Baratheon.

   She was fathered on a common woman by Robert during his teenage in Vale. Robert   liked to spend time with her when she was a child even after he broke off with her Mother.

   Mya has inherited the traditional Baratheon black hair, blue eyes and attractive jaw from her father. She now serves Lords of Vale, specifically House Royce.
2. [Joy Hill](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Joy_Hill) is a bastard of Gerion Lannister who was a brother to Lord Tywin Lannister. Physical description is not given, most likely a blonde like her father.
3. [Sand Snakes](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sand_Snakes) is a name given to Bastard daughters of Prince Oberyn Martell of Dorne. All of them have inherited looks from their mothers along with Oberyn's widowpeak.
4. [Barra Waters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Barra) was a bastard of King Robert Baratheon. She was murdered by Allar deem. She resembled her half sister Mya Stone so that means she got the same typical Baratheon features from Robert.
5. [Ellaria Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ellaria_Sand) is bastard daughter of [Lord Harmen Uller of Hellholt](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harmen_Uller). She was paramour of Prince Oberyn Martell of Dorne.
6. [Falia Flowers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Falia_Flowers) is bastard daughter of Lord Humfrey Hewett. She became paramour of Euron Greyjoy during one of his raids on Reach.
7. A prostitute [Bella](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bella) claims to be a bastard of King Robert Baratheon. She has the Baratheon black hair which gives credence to her claim. Not to mention the fact that Robert Baratheon did spend some time in brothels of her town during [Battle of the Bells](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Bells) & Robert was never shy when it came to making babies.

---

### Historical Bastards

Following female bastards were mentioned who existed before the current timeline of events:

1. [Alys Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alys_Rivers), a bastard from Riverlands,  was paramour of [Prince Aemond Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemond_Targaryen).
2. [Lynora Hill](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lynora_Hill), A bastard daughter of [Jason Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jason_Lannister_(son_of_Gerold)) who was brother of Lord Tytos Lannister. Physical description unavailable. Most likely a blonde like her father.
3. [Alysanne Waters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alysanne_(daughter_of_Aegon_IV)) was a bastard daughter of Prince Aegon Targaryen (Later King Aegon IV). She was sent off to become a Septa by her grandfather King Viserys II Targaryen.
4. [Lily Waters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lily) was a bastard daughter of Prince Aegon Targaryen (Later King Aegon IV). She was sent off to become a Septa by her grandfather King Viserys II Targaryen.
5. [Willow Waters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Willow_(daughter_of_Aegon_IV)) was a bastard daughter of Prince Aegon Targaryen (Later King Aegon IV). She was sent off to become a Septa by her grandfather King Viserys II Targaryen.
6. [Rosey Waters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rosey_(daughter_of_Aegon_IV)) was a bastard daughter of Prince Aegon Targaryen (Later King Aegon IV). She was sent off to become a Septa by her grandfather King Viserys II Targaryen.
7. [Bellanora Otherys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bellenora_Otherys) was another bastard daughter of King Aegon IV.
8. [Narha Otherys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Narha_Otherys) was another bastard daughter of King Aegon IV.
9. Princess [Mya "Rivers" Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mya_Rivers) was a legitimized bastard daughter of Lady Melissa Blackwood and King Aegon IV.
10. Princess [Gwenys "Rivers" Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gwenys_Rivers) was another legitimized bastard daughter of Lady Melissa Blackwood and King Aegon IV.
11. Princess [Shiera "Seastar" Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Shiera_Seastar) was legitimized bastard daughter of King Aegon IV and [Serenei](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Serenei_of_Lys) of Lys. She inherited the Valyrian looks of her parents and was one of the reason for enmity between her half brothers [Brynden Bloodraven](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers) and [Aegor Bittersteel](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegor_Rivers).
12. As kindly pointed out by [tchrist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3064/tchrist), I had missed one bastard daughter from the list. [Jeyne Waters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jeyne_Waters) was bastard daughter of Lord Alyn "Oakenfist" Velaryon and Princess Elaena Targaryen.

Comment: I'm really liking your presence in this site.

Comment: @Mooz I am honored

Comment: Jeyne Waters, the bastard daughter of Lord Alyn Velaryon and Princess Elaena Targaryen, founded House Longwaters when she married her full brother Jon Waters, a sibling marriage *“à la Targaryen”* as one might say. Their most notable descendent is Rennifer Longwaters, who was chief undergaoler of the Red Keep’s dungeons when Tyrion escaped.

Comment: Um, Myrcella "Baratheon"?

Comment: @WadCheber Myrcella is considered a trueborn Baratheon, not a bastard. That's why I didn't add her to my list

Answer (score 16):

Beyond Aegon's answer, I thought it would be worth mentioning that (first book spoilers)

> Princess Myrcella

is technically a bastard by blood, if not by status.

Comment: [You are technically correct. The best kind of correct](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/909/991/48c.jpg)

Comment: Not sure through. If the father has festered the child with other woman than registered wife then it is bastard. If the mother does the same, then the child do not have any status. It is not allowed for woman to have children with other man.

Comment: @ManojR Not really. Princess Daena the Defiant had a bastard son named Daemon Blackfyre. Similarly Princess Elaena had two bastard children. Lady Ashara Dayne had also allegedly given birth to a bastard.

Comment: But then again, none of them were married to another man at that time.

Answer (score 2):

She's from the Telltale game, which could be argued as less canon, but [Sera Flowers](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Sera_Flowers) is a highborn bastard who uses the name Durwell to hide the fact.

Comment: If I am not wrong, in game House Durwell was depicted as extinct. In Books however, even though no members are mentioned, Durwell are supposed to be neighbouring lords near lands of house Webber which implies they are not extinct

Comment: Ah yes Games say House Durwell died out 200 years ago. In Books, They are mentioned in The Sworn Sword which is set a 100 years before the current event. If they existed a 100 years before events in ASOIAF, that means games are wrong

Comment: @Aegon The games apparently follow the TV canon.

Answer (score 1):

I think the two I would consider most memorable are Mya Stone and the babe that

> was killed as part of Joffrey's rampage to kill all Robert's bastards. As someone else mentioned, Princess Myrcella is a bastard, but secretly so.. It is explicitly mentioned many times that her mother's husband is not her father, making her a bastard.